# Running of the fine structure constant

Tags: particle-physics, kinematics, experimental-physics, quantum-electrodynamics, scattering

In [Measurement of the Running of the Fine-Structure Constant](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ex/0002035), the L3 collaboration reports their fine structure constant data for various values of momentum transfer which they call $Q^2$.  This is the Mandelstam $t$ variable (pictured at bottom) associated with the the change in the positron's momentum during electron-positron scattering experiments.

I see that the positive and negative $Q^2$ correspong to momentum transfer by annihilation or scattering, but why do they call those cases "running in the spacelike region" or "running in the timelike region?"

My other question regards the actual running behavior.  The data on the left is from [Measurement of the running of the fine structure constant below 1 GeV with the KLOE Detector](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.06631) by the KLOE-2 Collaboration.  The data on the right is from the L3 paper linked above.  Unless I am reading this wrong, it seems to say that $\alpha(Q^2)$ inreases relative to $\alpha(0)$ for low momentum transfers (fraction greater than one on the left plot) and then goes below $\alpha(0)$ as $Q^2$ continues to increase (values less than 137 on the right plot.)  Am I reading that correctly?  What is a good source where I can find the currently accepted running behavior across the entire known window of $Q^2$?

Also, what is the reason for the strange kink in the KLOE data?

[image: Running of FSC in two Q^2 windows]

[image: Picture of Mandelstam coords in Bhabha scattering]

Comment: Try your particle physics text. The KlLOE-2 paper spends most of the paper explaining the jog, including the effects of the ρ(770) and  ω(782) in the dispersion relation which are precisely where the jog occurs: it is absent in the pure leptonic line.

Comment: @CosmasZachos So that I may better understand your comment, would you say which question you're answering?  For example, I haven't mentioned "jog," you don't say whay "jog" is, and the paper you cite doesn't contain the word "jog" either.  Therefore, I am unable to see what you're getting at.

Comment: Jog:= A protruding or receding part in  a line. I am referring to the "jump" in the KLOE-2 graph that confused you. This is what most of their paper is all about, no?

Comment: @CosmasZachos No, that's not what most of their paper is about.  You are clearly confused about the paper and you must be confused about where to ask your own questions: the comment section to my question isn't the right place.  If you want to know more about the paper, you could read it or ask your own question, which I will try to answer if I see it.  Thank you.

Comment: I did read it, and  the meat of the paper is of course section 6. I am pointing out that the jog/kink is  an "effective"  α variation, a hadronic feature of the measurement framework... If my comments distract you, I'm  relieved to desist...

Comment: @hodopsmith "You are clearly confused about the paper and you must be confused about where to ask your own questions". please, when you take an attitude towards a person answering your questions, have a look at the profile which you can access with a click on the name, where I got the bio https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/66086/cosmas-zachos . I would have felt honored if I got an explanation from him.